# mysql fetch all rows vs on demand select

Tags: php, mysql

im building an app in laravel (not relavant to this query i dont think).

there are a few user provided settings saved in a db table "settings".

for ease of use these values are being merged into the default config for the app (a simple php array) on boot, meaning i can just use 1 interface for accessing the values be they from the default config array, or overwritten by values in the db.

This currently means a `SELECT key,value FROM settings;` query is being used on boot before anything else.

im just wondering if anybody knows if this is sub optimal?

I dont anticipate more than 100 or so rows in this table, with around 60% ish being needed on every request.

Considering connection/lookup/return of a query would it be optimal to:

1. leave it as is and simply load all on boot
2. add a `autoload` column and only load settings with this true on boot and load the rest "on demand" (when there requested)
3. load every one "on demand"

as there are so few rows, and the data is two simple strings per row im guesssing just loading them all is overall as fast as loading a few and then the rest on demand which involves multiple connection requests.

Am i right or should i consider optimising via option 2/3 or another method?

Comment: Actually I would save the settings serialized into a file, so you can only open that file, unserialize it and overwrite the default values. This will prevent always reloading the same settings and if you decide to change a setting, you just can delete the cache file and write a new file with the new settings.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity (less complicated code), I would just load them all. So what if 40%-ish aren't going to be needed for a particular request.

It's a simple SQL statement. There aren't other variations of it (with different WHERE clauses) that need to be tested.

Overall, seems like it would be less code to test. I don't see the potential savings of the other alternatives. I can't justify the additional complexity.